# How to get selected/clicked object from ng-repeat into different array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

repeat function that goes through my array

```
 <div class="col-md-2  " ng-repeat="el in vm.recepti.slice(((vm.currentPage - 1) * vm.itemsPerPage), ((vm.currentPage) * vm.itemsPerPage))"
         style="padding:3px; ">
        <div class="thumbnail " style="display:inline-block; padding:10px; margin-bottom:2px; text-align:center;">
            <img src="{{el.image}}" style="width:200px;">
            <hr style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
            <a ng-click="vm.selektujRecept()"  style="color:black; cursor:pointer;"  data-placement="top" uib-tooltip="{{el.label}}">
                {{ el.label | limitTo: 16 }}{{el.label.length > 16 ? '...' : ''}}</a>
            <hr style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;"> ingredients:
            <a style="color:green; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{el.ingredientLines.toString();}}">{{el.ingredientLines.length}} </a>
            <br> calories:
            <a style="color:green; text-decoration: none;">{{el.calories| limitTo: 6}}{{el.label.length > 6 ? '' : ''}}</a>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
```

now i want to **get single object from that array** when i click on a link that has `function vm.selektujRecept();`
so i do this in javascript:

```
vm.recept=[];
vm.selektujRecept= function(el){


    vm.recept=el;
    console.log(vm.recept.label);

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the parameter to the `ng-click` function

```
ng-click="vm.selektujRecept(el)"
```

Comment: am i really that stupid , i didn't see that i was banging my hed off the wall how can i miss that , Thank you sir

Comment: @StefanBRT no problem. check this as answer if this helped :D

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are not passing any parameter to the function from the template,

change it as,

```
  <a ng-click="vm.selektujRecept(el)"
```

and **`vm.recept`**  should be an object,

```
vm.recept = {};

vm.selektujRecept= function(el){
    vm.recept=el;
    console.log(vm.recept.label);
};
```